# ¿como leer archivo excel de forma automatica?

Tags: python, excel

hola tengo un problema al leer un archivo Excel del cual necesito obtener un promedio anual de varias estaciones metrológicas así como los datos de longitud y latitud de cada uno como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta el momento puedo leer solo la primera estación(recuadro rojo) quisiera poder leer de manera automática varias estaciones en este formato

comparto mi codigo que me ayudo a calcular los promedios y a extraer los datos de longitud y latitud

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#leer el archivo desde el directorio
xls=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\prueba precipitacion.xlsx',skiprows=1)
df=pd.DataFrame(xls)
df=df.dropna(how='all',axis=1)
df=df.dropna(how='all',axis=0)

#suma y promedio de los promedios anuales
df1=df.iloc[:,1:]
df2=list(df1.mean(skipna=True,axis=1))
proman=sum(df2)/len(df2)
proman

#coordenadas de la primera estacion
wb=xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\prueba precipitacion.xlsx')
c=wb.sheets[0]
Longitud=c.range('D1').value
Latitud=c.range('F1').value
coordenadas=[Longitud,Latitud]
coordenadas
```

porfavor ayuda

Comment: separa los datos, eligelos por "secciones" o trozos usando `iloc` algo así `estacion1=df.iloc[:18, :]` y para la siguiente estación eliges otro trozo de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puedes utilizar las filas en blanco a tu favor para hacer un split del dataframe completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None)

dfs = np.split(df, df[df.isnull().all(1)].index). # Esta es la parte que te interesa

coordenadas = []
output = []
for i in dfs:
    i.dropna(how='all', axis=0, inplace=True)
    i.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
    if not i.empty:
        head = i.head(1).iloc[0:1]

        coordenadas.append({
            'estacion': i.head(1).iloc[0, 0],
            'latitud': i.head(1).iloc[0, 5],
            'longitud': i.head(1).iloc[0, 3],
        })

        i.columns = i.iloc[1]
        i = i[2:]
        output.append(i)
```

En output tendrás una lista con un dataframe por cada tabla encontrada y en coordenadas una lista con las propiedades de las estaciones

Comment: hola, me ha servido de mucho tu respuesta, pero existe un problemita cuando la separación entre estación y estación en el archivo excel es de 2 filas me da el siguiente error      IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. funciona perfectamente cuando la separación es de una fila

Comment: También puede ocurrirte que la estación no devuelva ningún registro y generaría otro fallo. Modifico mi respuesta para que evalue que el dataframe tiene datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para subir varios archivos excel uso este metodo

```
import pandas as pd
import functools
import glob

df = pd.concat(map(functools.partial(pd.read_excel, header=0, index_col=False),glob.glob("C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\prueba precipitacion/*.xlsx")))
```

para subir barias pues conectarías con la función concat y asi tendrias un solo df

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).